# Enabling default button sounds in ionic

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to make the default tock sound work when you click something in an app, but I have not come across a way to do it without recoding a lot of the app.  Specifically, I am looking if a button is pressed I want it to make a sound.  When I'm on my android for example, if I'm in Fb or gmail when I click something it makes a sound.  I am using Ionic 1.2 right now for the app.  Even when I use an emulator, it doesn't seem to make a sound - and it definitely doesn't do it in ionic view

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: My problem is I have an app with a lot of code, I couldn't possibly post all the code for it.  I'm looking for code that does this, I don't have any yet

Comment: Reasonable question without code. Presumably OPs code looks like `<button ion-button>foo</button>`. OP presumably wants to add a click noise to (a) this button and possibly (b) all other buttons in app without duplicating code.